# Split a large matrix in sub file horizontally

Tags: unix

I have a large matrix: around: 4G. I would like to split this large file into small sub files. To do this, I used the string:

```
split -b 500m my_matrix.txt  output_
```

This large matrix results from a computation and is 14.000 rows per 14.000 columns. Is it possible to split the main matrix (file) in sub files but still maintaining the number of columns equal to 14.000? Obviously only the number of rows will change.

Comment: use the `--lines` option

Comment: Added as an answer so that you can upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

From `man split`

```
   -l, --lines=NUMBER
          put NUMBER lines per output file
```